# why am I having this output as result?

Tags: javascript

what would be the result of my code ? I am expecting to have as result one single array of length 1 , I want to output only values of **d** variable that haven't been updated in my var2 variable but I get an array of length 2 , I  want to have output

> {name : "david", age : 23, day : 23}

```js
const d = [{name : '',age : '',day :23}]
const var2 =  [...d, { name : 'david', age : 22}]
console.log(var2)
```

Comment: make d just an object (as expected output), then do `const var2 =  {...d, ...{ name : 'david', age : 22}}`

Comment: You're trying to spread the object d into an array (var2) but that's not possible. Lawrence gave you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:

`d` is an `array` of `objects`

`{ name : 'david', age : 22}` is an `object literal`

When you use the `spread operator` on `d`, you are telling it to take each object in `d` and place it into `var2`, then at the end, append the `{ name : 'david', age : 22}`.

So the result would be an `array` with all the items you had in `d` + the object literal `{ name : 'david', age : 22}`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the spread operator correctly. You should use it to merge all elements of `d[0]` with an object containing your updated values.

```js
const d = [{name : '',age : '',day :23}]

// for d containing only one element 
const var2 =  [{...d[0], name : 'david', age : 22}]
// will result in [{name: '', age: '', day: 23, name: 'david', age: 22}] and be merged by keeping the right-most value

// for all elements in d
const var3 = d.map(el => { 
  return {...el, name : 'david', age : 22}
})

console.log(var2)
console.log(var3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your expected result `{name : "david", age : 23, day : 23}` merge two objects like shown below.

merge Object like `{...object1, ...object2}`

```js
const d = [{name : '',age : '',day :23}]
const var2 =  {...d[0], ...{ name : 'david', age : 22}}
console.log(var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator you use in line 2 is used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a list of some kind.

Basically what happens in your code ->

Array `d` has 1 item, so when you try to define `var2` it takes all elements from array `d` ( 1 in our case ) and add `{ name : 'david', age : 22}` to it.

In result you get array of two items.

For example:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3]
const array2 = [...array1,4, 5]

// array2 now is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

the (`...`) is `Array/Object spread operator` [js spread operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/)

What the code above does, is to spread over the `d` object and get all its properties, then overwrite the existing properties with the ones we’re passing. It copies the properties of the `d` object, over to the newly created object. So you are getting this output. Try the below code:

```html
<script>
const d = [{name : '',age : '',day :23}]
const var2 =  [{...d[0], name : 'david', age : 22}]
console.log(var2)

</script>
```

You can also achieve the same using below code

```html
<script>
const d = {name : '',age : '',day :23}
const var2 =  {...d, name : 'david', age : 22}
console.log(var2)
</script>
```

It will override the name and age